# C# dotnet "Require" and Assertions

Tags: c#, scala

From Scala language I am used to peppering my code with `require` statement.

I would use this for things that should NEVER be violated, it is a sanity check and also a kind of "live comment" in the code.

This is the behaviour I would like

```cs
// C#
if (!(x > 0)) {
  throw new Exception($"x must be positive but was ${x}")
}
```

but this is hard to read and will be a mess if there many of them at the top of the function.

In Scala I was used to doing this:

```scala
// Scala

require(x > 0, s"x must be positive but was ${x}")

// or just

require(x > 0)
```

It's not much effort to type `require(x>0)` and very readable.

I find these save me a lot of time when developing in Scala, it's very easy to type them out and often the sanity check catches a mistake fast.

What is the accepted way to do this in C# ?

I saw there are "Code Contracts" and I tried using these but they don't seem to work at all in .NET Core.

Comment: Well, you could write yourself a helper method like `void Require(bool isItFine, string formatString, params object[] args)` which would throw an exception (and format the message string) based on the boolean argument. You would then call it like (based on your C# example above): `Require(x > 0, "x must be positive but was {0}", x)` (note that i do not use string interpolation here to avoid the cost of creating unnecessary exception/message strings. Using separate argument for format string allows to create message string only when an exception is actually being thrown)

Comment: I’m not familiar with either language, and don’t know what the proper C# solution to this problem is, but it looks like you could easily write your own `require` method that you use all over the place. In the end, it looks like it’s simply a method that takes in a Boolean and optional String, and will raise an error if the Boolean is false, using the string (or some default string) in the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is relatively standard to see a long list of `if ... throw` at the beginning of methods, but there are the `Debug.Assert` (for assertions removed from release builds) and `Trace.Assert` (to keep the assertions in your release builds) methods that appear to be very similar to the Scala `require` method you mentioned.

See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/assertions-in-managed-code?view=vs-2017) about assertions on MSDN for details about how they work and the different overloads.

In your case you could write

```
Trace.Assert(x > 0, $"x must be positive but was ${x}");
```

Comment: I believe this approach to be more idiomatic

Answer (score 2):

#### [Code Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts)

Code contracts allow you to specify preconditions and post conditions in your code.

```
Contract.Requires(x != null);
```

and

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(x != null, nameof(x));
```

For post-conditions:

```
Contract.Ensures(this.F > 0);
```

and

```
Contract.EnsuresOnThrow<T>(this.F > 0);
```

There are other variations as well.  Check out the [Code Contracts Namespace.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Code Contracts appears abandoned https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/492